# Get curl past hazelcast login

Tags: curl, scripting, hazelcast, http-authentication

I am trying to curl the main page for our hazelcast mancenter. 
Some examples of curl commands in a script i've used:

```
curl -c cookies.txt -u foo:bar http://hazel01.us.domain.com/mancenter
curl -b cookies.txt -u foo:bar http://hazel01.us.domain.com/mancenter
```

and then

```
curl -c cookies.txt -d username=foo:password=bar http://hazel01.us.domain.com/mancenter
curl -b cookies.txt -d username=foo:password=bar http://hazel01.us.domain.com/mancenter
```

and so forth

always it just returns the curl output from the main login page.
Any ideas? Thanks.

***UPDATE***

I've realized that I was curl'ing /mancenter/login.jsp and have thus tried /mancenter/main.jsp and just /mancenter and this isn't returning anything.

Comment: you need to enable rest api for mancenter - http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/clusteredrest.html

Comment: So you're saying that the reason i'm not getting any return on /main.jsp is because the restapi is turned off?

Comment: no if you wish to hit cluster you should do it through rest endpoints like `clusters/dev/` or `clusters/dev/members/192.168.2.78:5701` - what are you trying acheive?

Comment: We need to be alerted when a node appears under the cluster health for awaiting migrations

Comment: see if you can utilize any of the endpoints under `URL: /rest/clusters/{clustername}/members/{member}` endpoint - http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/clusteredrest.html

Comment: No it doesn't look like i can hit any of those endpoints

Comment: Have you enabled Clustered REST on your nodes? It's not obvious from your responses so far. `-Dhazelcast.mc.rest.enabled=true`